# How does one sort with Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable?

Tags: arrays, sorting, haskell, vector

How can you sort a long list of data (strings, floats etc) that is read from a large file
(say a few million lines) using a Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable object and a sort algorithm
from Data.Vector.Algorithms?

Comment: Also, Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable is not an object, it's an abstract API for manipulating any type of mutable vector.  These include Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable, Data.Vector.Storable.Mutable, etc.

Answer (score 16):

Here's how to do it in the general case.

First, you need a mutable vector.  You can build this incrementally as
you scan the file; allocate a vector that's about as big as you need,
and increase the size and copy when you run out of space.  Or you can
read the entire file, count the record separators, and allocate the
right amount of space all at once.  This is easier but probably not
acceptable In Real Life.  (The expand-as-needed strategy is pretty
common; if you ever use a language like Perl and push lines you read
from a file onto the end of an array, this is what's happening.  Perl
allocates some space for an array, when you fill it, it increases the
amount of space, allocates new space, and copies.)

Anyway, I'm too lazy to do this, so I am just going to create a vector
with some random numbers in it.

We need a bunch of libraries for this:

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random
import qualified Data.Vector as IV
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as MV
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro as VA
```

We don't need this all at once, but we'll need it eventually, so I
thought I'd get it out of the way.

Anyway, our mutable vector is going to be a "normal" mutable vector,
here `MV.MVector`.

The idea of a mutable vector is that you create it and modify it in a
number of steps.  In Haskell, there are a few ways to make this look
pure to the calling code; one is to do it all inside the `ST` monad.
Your ST action is creating the vector, modifying it, and "freezing" it
into an immutable vector.  Internally, you are using fast
modify-this-memory-location-a-bunch-of-times operations, but
externally, you have something that is pure.  (Read the paper about
`ST` if you want an argument as to why this is safe.)

Another way to deal with mutable data is to just do it inside the
Everything, erm, `IO`, monad.  That's what we're going to do here, as
it's most convenient.

(`Data.Vector.Mutable` has two predefined vector types for you,
`IOVector` and `STVector`.  We're using `IOVector`, which puts all
the vector operations into `IO`.)

So like 8 paragraphs ago, we were going to create a mutable vector to
sort.  And here we are:

```
randVector :: IO (MV.IOVector Int)
randVector = do
  v <- MV.new 10
  forM [0..9] $ \x -> do
    r <- randomIO :: IO Int
    MV.write v x r
  return v
```

This is an IO action that returns a new mutable vector with 10 random
numbers inside it.  (Random number generation can also be conveniently
lifted into the IO monad, so we did that too, for convenience!  It's
like we're writing C, but with nicer syntax and more type safety.)

That's actually the hard part.  To do the sorting, I imported
`Data.Vector.Algorithms.Intro` which is basically an in-place
quicksort.  A function called `sort` does the actual sorting (in
whichever monad the mutable vector is in).

An action that creates the random mutable vector and sorts it in place
looks like:

```
sort = VA.sort =<< randVector
```

Now, to print that out, all we need to do is "freeze" the vector into
an immutable vector, and print out the `.toList`.  Or you can just
iterate over every element and print it.

Here's what I came up with as an example:

```
main = do
  v <- randVector
  VA.sort v
  iv <- V.unsafeFreeze v :: IO (IV.Vector Int)
  print . V.toList $ iv
```

`V.unsafeFreeze` is from `Data.Vector.Generic` (how you interact with
all vector types with the same API), as is `V.toList`.

Anyway, it's worth noting that IO is purely for convenience here.
Since you're building a vector from file data, it's appropriate.  99%
of the time, though, you should use `ST`.  In your ST action, create
the vector, sort it, freeze it, and return the frozen version.

A similar example using `STVector`:

```
randVector :: ST s (Vector Int)
randVector = do
  vec <- new 10
  rand <- newSTRef 17
  forM_ [0..9] $ \index -> do
    randN <- readSTRef rand
    let randN' = (fst . next . mkStdGen) randN
    writeSTRef rand randN'
    write vec index randN'
  unsafeFreeze vec
```

Then run with:

```
*Main> runST randVector
fromList [679560,1422110406,306332632,1905242129,692062628,393451229,355476175,1240028023,873588529,1181443777] :: Data.Vector.Vector
```

Comment: Thanks for your help jrockway.  I'm comfortable with the IO monad but I clearly need to learn about the ST monad.  Once I get your example code working I'll try to modify it to read from a file to load the vector rather than random numbers.

Comment: Thank you, thank you thank you. Much appreciated intro to ST, with good examples of general usage.